# Shell Script to change to another directory using variables in the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a simple shell script where on running this script it should change to another directory. I want to make it by allocating a variable to the path. `vi loc_change`

```
#!/bin/bash
change= "/home/oracle/Public"
cd $change
echo "directory changed"
```

after doing this I have changed the permissions 
`chmod 777 loc_change` and executing this `source ./loc_change` after executing this I am getting following error.

```
./loc_change: line 2: /home/oracle/Public: is a directory
directory changed
```

I have seen this type of decleration in [tldp](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf).
I am very new to Shell scripting.

Comment: Don't put a space between the = and the quotation mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
change="/home/oracle/Public"
```

remove the space

try,

```
 #!/bin/bash
 change="/rooot"
 cd $change > /dev/null > 2&>1
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then
 echo "Directory Changed"
 else
 echo "Directory Not changed"
 fi
```

Comment: haha yeah but I am getting error will do it once I reach minimum time

Comment: we can use like "#!/bin/bash
change="/rooot"
cd $change > /dev/null > 2&>1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "Directory Changed"
else
echo "Directory Not changed"
fi"

Comment: @RanjithkumarT yep, nice improvements. :).

Answer (score 0):

There should be no space.

```
#!/bin/bash
    change="/home/oracle/Public"
    cd $change
    echo "directory changed"
```